# IdentityServer4/Duende user consent

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have configured a client in my identity server to require consent.
When logging in, the consent page is shown and the user can accept or reject it.
When accepting, the result is saved to the PersistedGrantStore [dbo].[PersistedGrants] where I verified, that the row with type `user_consent` is present.

Still, the next time the user logs in, the consent page is shown again... why is that?
Do I have to do something in addition so that the consent page is only shown once (if accepted)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to control the prompt parameter:

```
AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
     options.Prompt = "consent";
     ...
}
```

For the possible values, see the specification [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).

Then you can also configure the consent settings in the backend here:
https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/models/client/

Here you have the following settings:

**RequireConsent**

Specifies whether a consent screen is required. Defaults to false.

**AllowRememberConsent**

Specifies whether user can choose to store consent decisions. Defaults to true.

**ConsentLifetime**

Lifetime of a user consent in seconds. Defaults to null (no expiration).

Comment: I have prompt: 'consent' configured in my testclient application. But the problem is, that it shows the consent page everytime even if the user has already given consent before

Comment: try to change it to some of the other possible values. see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/endpoints/authorize/

Comment: Hope my updated answer helps

Comment: The others don't work unfortunately. I have configured the client to RequireConsent, AllowRememberConsent and a ConsentLifetime of null. The consent is saved in the DB and the DefaultConsentService also is able to find the consent while logging in but still it shows the page despite the accepted consent being present